# Multiple set unions along with list comprehension

Tags: python, list, set, list-comprehension, union

I am trying to understand this code:

```
edit_two_set = set()
edit_two_set = set.union(*[edit_two_set.union(edit_one_letter(w, allow_switches)) for w in one])
```

Here *one* is a set of strings. *allow_switches* is True.
*edit_one_letter* takes in one word and makes either one character insertion, deletion or one switch of corresponding characters.

I understand:

```
[edit_two_set.union(edit_one_letter(w, allow_switches)) for w in one]
```

is performing a list comprehension in which for every word in one we make one character edit and then take the union of the resulting set with the previous set.

I am mainly stuck at trying to understand what:

```
set.union(*[])
```

is doing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to this:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union

The list comprehension returns a list of sets.

`set.union(*)` would perform a union of the sets within the list and return a new set.